# Regex to remove characters after multiple white spaces

Tags: python, regex

Hi all I've got and input strings:

```
list_of_strings = ["apple", "orange ca", "pear  sa", "banana    sth"]
```

And I want to remove everything after multiple white spaces (more than 1), so end result is:

```
final_list_of_strings = ["apple", "orange ca", "pear", "banana"]
```

I've tried regex:

```
import re

regex_expression = r"(.*\s?)(\s{2,}.*)"

for name in list_of_strings:
    regex_matching_groups = re.findall(regex_expression, name)
    if regex_matching_groups:
    name = regex_matching_groups[0][0]
```

but fails on multiple spaces ... Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` in a list comprehension:

```
import re
list_of_strings = ["apple", "orange ca", "pear  sa", "banana    sth"]
list_of_strings = [re.sub(r'\s{2}.*', '', x, flags=re.S) for x in list_of_strings]
print(list_of_strings)
# -> ['apple', 'orange ca', 'pear', 'banana']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TV5cl3).

The `\s{2}.*` regex matches two whitespace chars and then the rest of the string (even if there are line break chars due to `re.S` flag).

Comment: Perfect! I was too focused on re.findall() function ... Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

using a regular expression find the first word and optionally a second word with only one space between

```
list_of_strings = ["apple", "orange ca", "pear  sa", "banana    sth"]

my_list=[]
def find_phrase(list_of_strings):
    for string in list_of_strings:
        matches=re.findall(r"(\w+)( \w+)*", string)
        if len(matches)>0:
            my_list.append("".join([matches[0][0],matches[0][1]]))
    return my_list
        
 print(find_phrase(list_of_strings))
```

output:

```
['apple', 'orange ca', 'pear', 'banana']
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I try to avoid indexing like `matches[0][0]` in my code for cleanest. Thx!